# PowerPoint ExportAsFixedFormat exception

Tags: c#, ms-office, add-in, powerpoint

i have this code in a powerpoint addin but it's not working and giving me an exception. The exception says:

> "Value does not fall within expected range".

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

```
this.Application.ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat(path,
                    PpFixedFormatType.ppFixedFormatTypeXPS,
                    PpFixedFormatIntent.ppFixedFormatIntentPrint,
                    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, 
                    PpPrintHandoutOrder.ppPrintHandoutHorizontalFirst,
                    PpPrintOutputType.ppPrintOutputSlides,
                    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,
                    null,
                    PpPrintRangeType.ppPrintAll,
                    null,
                    true, 
                    true, 
                    true, 
                    false, 
                    false, 
                    null 
                    );
```

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the last value to "Missing.Value". That worked for someone here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb231096.aspx

Comment: Wow, that worked. I was focusing on the PrintRange all along. thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: @Alexander Cohen: You can select Nick's answer with the checkmark to indicate that it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

from the MSN doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb231096%28v=office.12%29.aspx

```
((MSPowerPoint.Presentation)this.Document).SaveAs(filename, MSPowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPDF, MsoTriState.msoCTrue);
```

HIH

Comment: Just used it to get a preview picture of the presentation (out of the .xps file) - works great via NetOffice! Didn't get ExportAsFixedFormat running.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when calling Excels ExportAsFixedFormat method when the path parameter approached 220 characters.  The filename limit in windows is 260 so that's odd, but shortening my file names solved my problem.